# I have memories, but none of my own

Tags: riddle

> I have memories, but none of my own,
>
> whatever's on my inside is what is shown.
>
> If I'm ever different it's because you changed me,
>
> I feel like a decoration, here for you to arrange me.

Comment: angsty teen song lyrics

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you are a:

> Photo Frame

I have memories, but none of my own,

> A photo frame holds photos which represent memories of the owner

whatever's on my inside is what is shown.

> The photo is inside the frame, and is displayed.

If I'm ever different it's because you changed me,

> The photo inside the frame can be changed by the owner.

I feel like a decoration, here for you to arrange me.

> Photo frames often are decorations.

Comment: This seems to me to be the most likely, though I will admit that my first guess was a Photo Album based solely on the plural "memories".

Answer (score 9):

I think you are a:

> Picture/Photo

I have memories, but none of my own,

> Pictures can hold different memories by taking a picture using a camera

Whatever's on my inside is what is shown

> Apparently what you see in a camera shows in a picture

If I'm different it's because you changed me

> Using photo editing software like photoshop

I feel like a decoration. here for you to arrange me

> Pictures are displayed and placed in frames

Answer (score 2):

I think you are a:

> Etch-a-sketch

I have memories, but none of my own,

> It records an image created by the user

Whatever's on my inside is what is shown

> The powder inside is seen through the screen

If I'm different it's because you changed me

I feel like a decoration. here for you to arrange me

> The user draws lines in the powder

Answer (score 2):

You are a

> computer (PC)

I have memories, but none of my own,

> computers have RAM, but it's empty, without being filled/loaded by its software

whatever's on my inside is what is shown.

> a PC show what the software inside tells it to show

If I'm ever different it's because you changed me,

> (hardware bugs, RNGs and stray cosmic rays aside,) computers are deterministic - running the same software with the same inputs results in the same outputs.

I feel like a decoration, here for you to arrange me.

> a PC without anything installed is just a doorstop. It's up to the user to install the software & customize it.

Answer (score 1):

a potential answer can be :

> A riddle

I have memories, but none of my own,

> A riddle is basically a creation of someone's mind including different phrases sentences which that creator have in his memory/mind.

whatever's on my inside is what is shown.

> This basically means that whatever is the answer of that riddle is in the words we just have to think correctly by reading what is shown to us in the form of that riddle.

If I'm ever different it's because you changed me,

> This can be related to types of riddles being beautifully created by different people for example of one the trending riddle which is the riley riddle.

I feel like a decoration, here for you to arrange me.

> A riddle is often beautifully presented to solve in form of rhymes or story and we have to decode it by thinking appropriately and solve it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that came to mind

I think you are a:

> Heart

I have memories, but none of my own,

> "They will always live in your heart/in here *taps chest*"

Whatever's on my inside is what is shown

> "Wearing your heart on your sleeve", emotions expressed

If I'm different it's because you changed me

> "Having a change of heart"

I feel like a decoration. here for you to arrange me

> Valentines and numerous other uses of hearts in culture/emojis/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a:

> book/library?

I have memories, but none of my own,

> Books and libraries both hold memories (texts) of other people

whatever's on my inside is what is shown.

> Taking a literal meaning here, what's in the book/library is what's shown to the reader

If I'm ever different it's because you changed me,

> If I were an author, I could change a book by the words I put into it.  Alternatively, a book could be vandalized, highlighted, etc.  If a library, I could donate books to change their collection, or borrow/steal a book and the library's collection would be altered.

I feel like a decoration, here for you to arrange me.

> Let's face it, lots of books sit on the shelf, and in a library in particular they may be arranged quite often.